# host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ds [bit 21] Does this warn affect virtual machine performance or use?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I found a lot of warning from the VM qemu log, Does this warn affect virtual machine performance or use? , is my libvirt.xml file problem? Or support hot-plug will have these warnings

This is my libvirt xml configuration:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='315'>
  <name>instance-000005b2</name>
  <uuid>793fe065-36a6-4840-80cf-840ebed41d3e</uuid>
  <maxMemory slots='32' unit='KiB'>68719476736</maxMemory>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='auto'>8</vcpu>
  <vcpus>
    <vcpu id='0' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='no' order='1'/>
    <vcpu id='1' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='2'/>
    <vcpu id='2' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='3'/>
    <vcpu id='3' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='4'/>
    <vcpu id='4' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='5'/>
    <vcpu id='5' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='6'/>
    <vcpu id='6' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='7'/>
    <vcpu id='7' enabled='yes' hotpluggable='yes' order='8'/>
  </vcpus>
  <cputune>
    <shares>2048</shares>
    <vcpupin vcpu='0' cpuset='0-9,20-29'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='1' cpuset='0-9,20-29'/>
    <emulatorpin cpuset='0-9,20-29'/>
  </cputune>
  <numatune>
    <memory mode='strict' nodeset='0'/>
    <memnode cellid='0' mode='strict' nodeset='0'/>
  </numatune>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.3.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
    <numa>
      <cell id='0' cpus='0-1' memory='2097152' unit='KiB'/>
    </numa>
  </cpu>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I found a lot of warning from the VM qemu log, Does this warn affect virtual machine performance or use? , is my libvirt.xml file problem? Or support hot-plug will have these warnings?

The following warn log：

```
2017-09-14T12:16:03.441702Z qemu-kvm: warning: CPU(s) not present in any NUMA nodes: 2 3 4 5 6 7
2017-09-14T12:16:03.441773Z qemu-kvm: warning: All CPU(s) up to maxcpus should be described in NUMA config
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ds [bit 21]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.acpi [bit 22]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ht [bit 28]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.tm [bit 29]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.pbe [bit 31]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.dtes64 [bit 2]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.monitor [bit 3]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ds_cpl [bit 4]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.smx [bit 6]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.est [bit 7]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.tm2 [bit 8]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xtpr [bit 14]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.pdcm [bit 15]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.dca [bit 18]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.osxsave [bit 27]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ds [bit 21]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.acpi [bit 22]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ht [bit 28]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.tm [bit 29]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.pbe [bit 31]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.dtes64 [bit 2]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.monitor [bit 3]
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ds_cpl [bit 4]
```

Comment: did you able to resolve it? I am getting into same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try:

```
mode='host-passthrough'
```

instead of:

```
mode='host-model'
```

Comment: why?    what different between the host-passthough and host-model

Comment: worked for me, seems like this was changed over the time